# Coordinate ring of $GL_2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, representation-theory

Let $GL_2$ be the group of all 2 by 2 invertible matrices over a field $K$. Let $x_{ij}$ be the function on $GL_2$ such that $x_{ij}(a) = a_{ij}$ for $a = (a_{ij}) \in GL_2$. Is the coordinate ring $K[GL_2]$ of $GL_2$ equal to
\begin{align}
K[x_{11}, x_{12}, x_{21}, x_{22}] 
\end{align}
or
\begin{align}
K[x_{11}, x_{12}, x_{21}, x_{22}, \frac{1}{x_{11}x_{22} - x_{12}x_{21}}]?  
\end{align}
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you even think that it is $K[x_{11},x_{12},x_{21},x_{22}]$, i.e. the coordinate ring of $\mathbb{A}^{2 \times 2}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the latter. $GL_2$ is an open subvariety of $\mathbb{A}^4$ and the complement is just the hypersurface $\det =0$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a polynomial  ring of 5 independent indeterminates, $K[x_{11},x_{12},x_{21},x_{22},y]$. Look at the closed affine sub-variety in $\mathbf{A^5}$ defined by the single equation $y(x_{11}x_{22}-x_{12}x_{21})-1=0$. If we rearrange the equation, on the zero locus, $y$ will be the reciprocal of the determinant function on the remaining 4 variables.

Now it is easy to define a $K$-algebra isomorphism of this variety's co-ordinate  ring with the ring in your question.

In general this idea can be imitated to show that the non-zero locus of a single polynomial in $m$ variables is actually the zero locus of suitably defined polynomial in $m+1$ variables, rather isomorphic to it.